# DOM Node ,, Why html.childNode[2] is body?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>document</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

why html.childNode[2] is BODY ??

I think html.childNode[0] is HEAD. and
html.childNode[1] is BODY.

But, html.childNode[1] is #text.
why this happens??
I can't see any text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 - is the `head`.
1 - is a text node - that linefeed between closing `</head>` and opening `<body>`. If you remove the line break, body will have the index 1.

Comment: Shouldn't 0 also be a text node then?

Comment: In the context of XML DOM I think it should actually. Well, looks like in HTML this is a special case.

Comment: Yes, as [the HTML parser spec says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode):  13.2.6.4.3 The "before head" insertion mode [...]  A character token that is one of U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION, U+000A LINE FEED (LF), U+000C FORM FEED (FF), U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR), or U+0020 SPACE - Ignore the token.

Answer (score 0):

as say in the doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

> childNodes includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment.

to get only child node element you have to use element.children

```js
var html = document.querySelector('html');

console.log(html.children[0]);
console.log(html.children[1]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>document</title>
</head>
<body></body>

</html>
```